# Team Git Workflow Setup

Tags: git, svn, repository, share

I am working on a project with a group of around 10 people.  I am trying to make it so each person has a remote repository they can push to in which everyone can fetch from.  There will also be a blessed repository in which everyone (except manager) can fetch from.

Note - Developers will be using the Eclipse plugin once this is all in place.

How do I make it so users can fetch from each others repositories but not push to them?  When I set permissions to 744 users are unable to even pull from that repository.

Any help would be greatly appreciated this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Are you creating a unique remote repository for every member of the group?  If so, why?

Comment: No problem there. Each member has their local repo and their own remote. All member can Fetch from each others remote repositories too. However I want to make it so they can only push to their remote repository and not everyone else's.

Comment: Does each remote repository contain a unique project, or is the group all working on the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to have one central repository, with a branch for each dev. These branches have their permission set so they're writable only the developer who owns it. Of course each dev has it's own local repository and can pull from other branches on the remote repo.

You get the same functionality you  want, but with one remote instead of 10, much easier to administrate.

[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) allows you to set a repository with such fine per-branch permission.

Comment: Is Gitolite the only way to control these branch permissions...what happens when a dev wants to create a branch to try something new... is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's the only way but it's the most widely used. Devs can do anything they want on their local repo, of course, permissions are only effective on the central remote. Local repo aren't shared at all.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at gitolite. Gitosis is no longer actively developed.

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite